# Which is this VSCode Theme?

Tags: fonts, colors, visual-studio-code, themes

I'm looking for a theme that I saw in the new update log of Visual Studio code. You can see it in this image.

[image]

Here is the link: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_file-and-folder-icons-in-intellisense

Does anyone know which is this **theme and font**?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure but I think it could be GitHub Plus Theme

Comment: It's not, near but not. Thank you.